# Regular loss of network connection

Tags: networking, router

For a week now my router completly looses the network connection times and times again. Sometimes it works for a couple of hours, sometimes only for 30mins at a time. It is usually able to reconnect after ~15mins.

The weird thing to me is that it happens not only randomly but everytime I

- Open the reddit app on my phone (*tested* at least 20 times)
- Try to download a file from Dropbox (... 5 or 6 times)
- Try to download something on Steam (Not 100% sure on this one)
- Have my phone perform updates from the Google Play Store (Tried 2 or 3 times so unsure here as well)

These all seem to be somewhat bandwidth-intense operations, at least for a short amount of time. It however does not happen when

- watching youtube videos
- downloading large assets from the Unity store

I replaced my router with a second one of the same (rather old, Speedport W723V Type A, Firmware 1.01.022) make and model, both with the newest firmware without any change. I also contacted my ISP which has not been really helpful so far.

Since there seems to be some logic behind it I would love to get an idea of the reasoning. Even if the problem is not on my end (which I assume), maybe to point my ISP in the correct direction to get this situation sorted which is, as you might imaging, very very annoying.

During a disconnected phase, `tracert` brings up

```
tracert -d 8.8.8.8

Routenverfolgung zu 8.8.8.8 über maximal 30 Hops

  1     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
  2  192.168.2.101  meldet: Zielhost nicht erreichbar.

Ablaufverfolgung beendet.
```

and `ping` a random collection of the following

```
ping -t 8.8.8.8

Ping wird ausgeführt für 8.8.8.8 mit 32 Bytes Daten:
Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
Antwort von 192.168.2.101: Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Allgemeiner Fehler.
```

Comment: `tracert -d 8.8.8.8`, `ping -t` first three hops and see where disconnect really happens.
If your gateway is fine, and first hope after it looses packets, then it could be ISP switch port fried.

Comment: That, or it does some sort of load-balancing because you're not alone on the local loop. If your "neighbors" (not geographically-speaking, but the people connected to the same local loop or DSLAM) use triple-play, for example, the bandwidth demand could be too high for you to get any connection at all from time to time. This said, you're right, it has to do with bandwidth use and distribution.

Comment: Talk to your ISP. They can troubleshoot from their end.

Comment: Windows machine is connected via cable. Since this also happens when the machine is offline and I only use my phone I don't think so, but will give it a try nonetheless.

Comment: Added model and firmware. Both are of Type A

Comment: Thanks, while waiting for different cable results just wanted to confirm it's the latest version for that type (as of now from 12/2019).

Comment: Tried a different cable. Worked fine for a while. Opened Reddit app and immediately gone. I now have a different router coming here in a few hours. Maybe that helps. Otherwise a technician will take a look in two days but I doubt he will find an issue on my end

Comment: Since you have two routers handy, can you try to bridge your connection and check if you still get those dropdowns in that configuration?

Comment: So, it works perfectly with a Fritzbox 7490. Doing a few tests shows I am currently able to download with speeds of over 60 Mbit/s. The W723V is only able to handle VDSL50, not 100. Could it be, that the higher speeds I get for whatever reason confuse the router enough to somewhat crash it?